# Table body preparation using jquery in run time is causing design issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

table row and data is not forming in the correct format

here is the fiddle link to the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/otc056L9/

Below is the HTML code

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%" class="eventtable">
    <thead style="color: blue">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Field Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblEntity"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appeding both `td` and input (and `figure.text`) to `tr`, because `tr.append("<td>")` returns `tr` again for chainability.

Correct code could be something like this:

```
// Adding the input into the row
tr.append("<td>").find('td').append(input);

// Your text
tr.append("<td>").find('td').append(Column.figure.text);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/otc056L9/1/

Or you can use [`$.fn.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method instead like this:

```
$("<td>").appendTo(tr).append(input);
```

Comment: And  var tr = $('#tblEntity').append('<tr>') assigns $('#tblEntity') to variable tr